# Uber Rush delivery update fails (sandbox)

Tags: uber-api

Making the following request fails for all the deliveries I have tried (except the first one when it worked once yesterday).

```
curl -X PUT https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/deliveries/e4084dd3-9152-4cb8-8748-2200715a5eca   -H "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>"   -d "{\"status\":\"en_route_to_pickup\"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

The above fails with error code 400 and body

```
{
  "message": "Bad request for delivery update",
  "code": "bad_delivery_update"
}
```

Any idea what may be wrong with the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status that you're updating to must be part of a valid state transition, as shown in the diagram on the [Delivery Statuses page](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rush/statuses). If the current status is `en_route_to_pickup`, then the next status must be `at_pickup`.

Comment: Hey @alec I am having bit of issue using uber-api, please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282763/uber-deeplink-and-universal-url-crashes-android-application?noredirect=1#comment87776275_50282763