# Uber deeplink and universal url crashes android application

Tags: uber-api

I am experiencing problem on Android with opening of Uber deeplink and universal url, uber hangs to a white screen and returns to calling activity on back presses.

I have tried:
Method 1:

```
SessionConfiguration config = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
                .setClientId(<client-id>)
                .setClientSecret(<client-secret>)
                .setServerToken(<server-token>)
                .build();

        Location location = Singleton.getInstance(context).getOneTimeLocation().getLocation();
        RideParameters rideParams = new RideParameters.Builder()
                .setPickupLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), "Your", "Your")
                .setDropoffLocation(latitude, longitude, address, "")
                .build();

        RideRequestDeeplink deeplink = new RideRequestDeeplink.Builder(context)
                .setSessionConfiguration(config)
                .setFallback(Deeplink.Fallback.MOBILE_WEB)
                .setRideParameters(rideParams)
                .build();

       // deeplink.execute();

        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(deeplink.getUri());
            ((BaseActivity) context).startActivity(intent, null, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

**Note:
In Method 1, I tried both *deeplink.execute()* and opening intent with *ACTION_VIEW* to redirect to browser.**

Method 2:

```
    String baseUrl = "https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup&";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append(baseUrl); 
    stringBuilder.append("client_id=").append(<client-id>).append("&");
stringBuilder.append("pickup[latitude]=").append(location.getLatitude()).append("&"); 
    stringBuilder.append("pickup[longitude]=").append(location.getLongitude()).append("&"); 
    stringBuilder.append("dropoff[latitude]=").append(latitude).append("&"); stringBuilder.append("dropoff[longitude]=").append(longitude).append("&"); 
    stringBuilder.append("dropoff[formatted_address]=").append(address); 
    //Opened this url in browser ending in same result
```

Both the methods had same result, Uber app hangs with white screen.

**In Method 2, it provides me with *Open link with chrome or uber*, if i choose *Just Once* it opens correctly but if it choose *Always* option it keeps redirecting me to hang Uber. If i resume this uber in hang state i.e. press home and reselect uber from running application it opens up with supplied data**

Comment: @DustinWhittle can i get some help here!

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this problem.

Comment: @KyleDavis, And i couldn't get it to work  on any android device. Everytime ending in same result, uber opens and hangs. If i resume this uber instance, it opens with the supplied parameters.

Comment: Interesting-- I am using Android and can't repro. Will keep looking but may be hard to diagnose. Just to cover our bases, you might want to check you are using the most recent version of the Uber app.

Comment: Yes i am using the latest version, let me share the video for the same. PS:-  Uber sdk is required for Method 1 but method 2 should work without uber sdk right??  Here is the link to the video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_ZRTenYk305vBiIhTk1gNCMZTH27n-1x/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Any more insight I can get into this @KyleDavus

Comment: @KyleDavis can you connect me to someone who can look into this